# Why do I not see any cases in specific case views when checking on mobile?

Tags: case, list-view, view, custom-view

I've been meaning to ask this for awhile now...

I have personal case views created in salesforce. When I view these from a desktop, they work fine.  But if I try to view them via the salesforce mobile app (or just via a mobile browser), salesforce states that there isn't any cases in the view (when I know there are). Has anyone else seen this? How can I get case lists to show properly on mobile?

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at all cases? And not the 'Recent' ones? By default, the listing shows Recent

Comment: Yes, I am selecting a custom view from the list of case views.